How to get in a candlestick ECHARTS graph candles solid/hollow and how to get the volumns all of a color
I'm trying to making a widget for time and have a view of my favorite stock on the stock market. So after some searching I'm using ECharts that seem the best since now.
However the charts in the examples on ECharts's site should be completed because according to the definition they should have full and empty candles as well as colored ones.
Take some seconds to read carefully this:


Solid candles show that the current close price is less than the current open price.
Hollow candles show that the current close price is greater than the current open price.
Red candles show that the current close price is less than the previous close price.
Green candles show that the current close price is greater than the previous close price.

Source: Wikipedia - Candlestick chart (see the link if you want to know more)

Solid and hollow candles
So how to make a chart like this with candles solid and hollow.
How I would like it to be (but with colors):

(Source: Wikipedia - Candlestick chart)
Colored like this https://ibb.co/1fhsPrf
(Source: tradingview.com - Title: Tesla)
Uniform volumn color
Also I want to know how to have the volumns all of a color (example: azure) (together on the same grid, candles and volumns, not 2 grids).
How I would like volumns:


P.S.
I would also like to point out (if any of the creators of ECharts  reads) that the volumns are sometimes a color that does not correspond to the rise or fall (e.g. it may happen that it is red if the stock goes up).
EDIT
After days of discussion in the comments of the answers the user @rozsazoltan has provided a satisfactory answer.
But I do not intend to split the points. I would like to insert them as dataset: { source: rawData, }, because it will be easier to update the graph dynamically.
Now, assuming that the code for the data is
rawData = [
  ["2004-01-02",10452.74,10409.85,10367.41,10554.96,168890000,-1,1],
  ["2004-01-05",10411.85,10544.07,10411.85,10575.92,221290000,1,-1],
  ["2004-01-06",10543.85,10538.66,10454.37,10584.07,191460000,1,1],
  ["2004-01-07",10535.46,10529.03,10432,10587.55,225490000,-1,-1],
  ["2004-01-08",10530.07,10592.44,10480.59,10651.99,237770000,-1,1],
  ["2004-01-09",10589.25,10458.89,10420.52,10603.48,223250000,1,-1],
  ["2004-01-12",10461.55,10485.18,10389.85,10543.03,197960000,1,1],
  ["2004-01-13",10485.18,10427.18,10341.19,10539.25,197310000,-1,1],
  ["2004-01-14",10428.67,10538.37,10426.89,10573.85,186280000,1,-1],
  ["2004-01-15",10534.52,10553.85,10454.52,10639.03,260090000,-1,1],
];

where each array is [date, open, close, low, high, volumn, red/green, solid/hollow]
[the last two values are random generated f*ke data just for trying]
Is there a way to get a function (or by using a plugin) for assigning visually in the graph red/green color, solid/hollow candlestick without splitting the data in series.data?
If there's not the better answer it's of @rozsazoltan, but I think it's legitimate to ask for a solution that fits more precisely.

If you need a jsfiddle to work on it, already ready here: https://jsfiddle.net/bo4hv3dn/

To customize individual elements in a candlestick chart, I did some research. Initially, I intended to use the traditional approach where itemStyle.[parameter] is assigned a function instead of a fixed string value, but I encountered the same issue as described in apache/echarts #12840 issue.
Following that, instead of using dataset.source for data transfer, I split the data set into two parts: values (candlestickData and volumeData for two series) and labels (dateData for X Axis). I extracted the dates as dateData and collected the remaining values as candlestickData and volumeData.
By doing this, candlestickData and volumeData is passed to the series.data parameter, which allows for injecting custom itemStyle. When injecting a custom itemStyle, the item is an object rather than an array, where the data is added through the value parameter. See the example for details.


var chartDom = document.getElementById('main')
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom)

const upColor = '#00da3c'
const downColor = '#ec0000'

// You can assemble rawData based on any logic you choose, and apply the appropriate custom colors to the relevant places
// Thats a static example, where 2nd item will custom
var rawData = [
  ["2004-02-02", 10487.78, 10499.18, 10395.55, 10614.44, 224800000],
  // Changed, example custom item
  {
    value: ["2004-02-03", 10499.48, 10505.18, 10414.15, 10571.48, 183810000],
    // I looked into it, and in the case of custom coloring, there is no color0 and borderColor0; you have to decide whether it's decreasing or not
    itemStyle: {
      color: 'purple',
      // color0: 'blue',
      borderColor: 'purple',
      // borderColor0: 'blue',
    },
  },
  ["2004-02-04", 10503.11, 10470.74, 10394.81, 10567.85, 227760000],
  ["2004-02-05", 10469.33, 10495.55, 10399.92, 10566.37, 187810000],
]

// Added
let dateData = []        // for X axis
let candlestickData = [] // for candlestick chart
let volumeData = []      // for volume bars

// Added
// Process rawData to separate candlestick data and custom styles
rawData.forEach(item => {
  // Standard item (only values)
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    dateData.push(item[0])                  // Date data
    candlestickData.push(item.slice(1, 5))  // [open, close, low, high]
    volumeData.push(item[5])                // Volume data
  }
  // Custom item with styling
  else if (item && item.value && Array.isArray(item.value)) {
    dateData.push(item.value[0])            // Date data
    candlestickData.push({
      value: item.value.slice(1, 5),        // [open, close, low, high]
      itemStyle: item.itemStyle             // Custom itemStyle
    })
    volumeData.push(item.value[5])          // Volume data
  }
})

myChart.setOption({
  animation: false,
  legend: {
    bottom: 10,
    left: 'center',
    data: ['Dow-Jones index'],
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'cross',
    },
  },
  axisPointer: {
    link: [{ xAxisIndex: 'all' }],
  },
  toolbox: {
    feature: {
      dataZoom: { yAxisIndex: false },
    },
  },
  grid: [
    { left: '10%', right: '8%', height: '50%' },
    { left: '10%', right: '8%', top: '63%', height: '16%' },
  ],
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      // Added
      data: dateData,             // Use the date data here
      boundaryGap: false,
      axisLine: { onZero: false },
      splitLine: { show: false },
      min: 'dataMin',
      max: 'dataMax',
    },
    {
      type: 'category',
      gridIndex: 1,
      // Added
      data: dateData,             // Use the date data here
      boundaryGap: false,
      axisLine: { onZero: false },
      axisTick: { show: false },
      splitLine: { show: false },
      axisLabel: { show: false },
      min: 'dataMin',
      max: 'dataMax',
    },
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      scale: true,
      splitArea: { show: true },
    },
    {
      scale: true,
      gridIndex: 1,
      splitNumber: 2,
      axisLabel: { show: false },
      axisLine: { show: false },
      axisTick: { show: false },
      splitLine: { show: false },
    },
  ],
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'inside',
      xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
      start: 0,
      end: 100,
    },
    {
      show: true,
      xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
      type: 'slider',
      top: '85%',
      start: 0,
      end: 100,
    },
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Dow-Jones index',
      type: 'candlestick',
      // Added
      data: candlestickData,     // Processed data with custom styles
      // Changed
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'transparent',    // Default color for upward movement
        color0: downColor,       // Default color for downward movement
        borderColor: upColor,    // Default border color for upward movement
        borderColor0: downColor, // Default border color for downward movement
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Volume',
      type: 'bar',
      // Added
      data: volumeData,          // Volume data
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      // Added
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'azure',          // Uniform volume color
      },
    },
  ],
})
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>



In my code, the sole purpose was to illustrate how you can assign custom colors to a specific element. Which element and the logic you want to apply is up to you; it’s an additional detail that’s not essential to the solution.
Updated
Passing the data to a function that computes a style is a good idea. (See the previous comments for context.) I'll write an example for you.
const getItemStyle = (values) => {
  if (values[1] > 10490 && values[1] < values[2]) {
    // I looked into it, and in the case of custom coloring, there is no color0 and borderColor0; you have to decide whether it's decreasing or not
    return {
      color: 'purple',
      borderColor: 'purple',
    }
  }
  
  if (values[1] > 10490 && values[1] > values[2]) {
    // I looked into it, and in the case of custom coloring, there is no color0 and borderColor0; you have to decide whether it's decreasing or not
    return {
      color: 'blue',
      borderColor: 'blue',
    }
  }
  
  // If you don't need custom coloring, the result should be undefined
  return undefined
}

For a working example, see the code snippet below.
Update # 2
It's not necessary to pass the data with the default settings, so I moved the data organization to the end of the snippet. There, the rawData is passed to a new updateChartData function, which clears the current data, inserts the new ones with updated coloring, and finally refreshes the chart values.
Known issue: The only drawback of this logic is that, for example, with 1-2 updates per second, it involves a lot of operations, so I wouldn't recommend it for that. I'm leaving it here just as a point of interest.
For frequent live updates (even on any element of the chart), I would rather use a proxy or reactivity to monitor changes and only modify the updated elements.


var chartDom = document.getElementById('main')
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom)

const upColor = '#00da3c'
const downColor = '#ec0000'

// You can assemble rawData based on any logic you choose, and apply the appropriate custom colors to the relevant places
// Thats a static example, where 2nd item will custom
var rawData = [
  ["2004-02-02", 10487.78, 10499.18, 10395.55, 10614.44, 224800000],
  ["2004-02-03", 10499.48, 10505.18, 10414.15, 10571.48, 183810000],
  ["2004-02-04", 10503.11, 10470.74, 10394.81, 10567.85, 227760000],
  ["2004-02-05", 10469.33, 10495.55, 10399.92, 10566.37, 187810000],
]

// Added
let dateData = []        // for X axis
let candlestickData = [] // for candlestick chart
let volumeData = []      // for volume bars

// Added
// Calculating the itemStyle based on the [date, open, close, low, high] values
// You can add as many different returns with any coloring and conditions as you like; I’ve just created one
const getItemStyle = (values) => {
  if (values[1] > 10490 && values[1] < values[2]) {
    // I looked into it, and in the case of custom coloring, there is no color0 and borderColor0; you have to decide whether it's decreasing or not
    return {
      color: 'purple',
      borderColor: 'purple',
    }
  }
  
  if (values[1] > 10490 && values[1] > values[2]) {
    // I looked into it, and in the case of custom coloring, there is no color0 and borderColor0; you have to decide whether it's decreasing or not
    return {
      color: 'blue',
      borderColor: 'blue',
    }
  }
  
  // If you don't need custom coloring, the result should be undefined
  return undefined
}

// Added
// Automatically adding a new element to everything
const pushItemToChart = (values) => {
  dateData.push(values[0]) // Date data
  candlestickData.push({
    value: [
      values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4] // [open, close, low, high]
    ],
    itemStyle: getItemStyle(values), // Custom itemStyle
  })
  volumeData.push(values) // Volume data
}
// If you pass the newly fetched live data to this pushItemToChart function, they will be added to all arrays, and we will process the value to determine if it requires unique coloring. Of course, this only works if you don't want to modify the coloring of the already existing elements.

// Set chart default options
myChart.setOption({
  animation: false,
  legend: {
    bottom: 10,
    left: 'center',
    data: ['Dow-Jones index'],
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'cross',
    },
  },
  axisPointer: {
    link: [{ xAxisIndex: 'all' }],
  },
  toolbox: {
    feature: {
      dataZoom: { yAxisIndex: false },
    },
  },
  grid: [
    { left: '10%', right: '8%', height: '50%' },
    { left: '10%', right: '8%', top: '63%', height: '16%' },
  ],
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      // Added
      // // data: dateData,             // Use the date data here
      boundaryGap: false,
      axisLine: { onZero: false },
      splitLine: { show: false },
      min: 'dataMin',
      max: 'dataMax',
    },
    {
      type: 'category',
      gridIndex: 1,
      // Added
      // // data: dateData,             // Use the date data here
      boundaryGap: false,
      axisLine: { onZero: false },
      axisTick: { show: false },
      splitLine: { show: false },
      axisLabel: { show: false },
      min: 'dataMin',
      max: 'dataMax',
    },
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      scale: true,
      splitArea: { show: true },
    },
    {
      scale: true,
      gridIndex: 1,
      splitNumber: 2,
      axisLabel: { show: false },
      axisLine: { show: false },
      axisTick: { show: false },
      splitLine: { show: false },
    },
  ],
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'inside',
      xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
      start: 0,
      end: 100,
    },
    {
      show: true,
      xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
      type: 'slider',
      top: '85%',
      start: 0,
      end: 100,
    },
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Dow-Jones index',
      type: 'candlestick',
      // Added
      // // data: candlestickData,     // Processed data with custom styles
      // Changed
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'transparent',    // Default color for upward movement
        color0: downColor,       // Default color for downward movement
        borderColor: upColor,    // Default border color for upward movement
        borderColor0: downColor, // Default border color for downward movement
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Volume',
      type: 'bar',
      // Added
      // // data: volumeData,          // Volume data
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      // Added
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'azure',          // Uniform volume color
      },
    },
  ],
})

// Rescan all data
// Process (raw)Data to separate candlestick data and custom styles
const updateChartData = (data) => {
  // Clear
  dateData = []        // for X axis
  candlestickData = [] // for candlestick chart
  volumeData = []      // for volume bars
  // Push
  data.forEach(values => {
    pushItemToChart(values)
  })
  
  // Update data in Chart
  myChart.setOption({
    xAxis: [
      { data: dateData }, // xAxis for candlestick
      { data: dateData }, // xAxis for volume
    ],
    series: [
      { data: candlestickData }, // series for candlestick
      { data: volumeData }, // series for volume
    ],
  })
}
updateChartData(rawData)
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>




Better. Much much better. It's this what I'm talking about. This was the part of the function that I told you should act externally. What you did is very complicated. Tomorrow/the day after tomorrow I will look at it better and tell you if it is feasible. Tnx. P.S. Sure if there was a way to just add a 1 or a -1 to the individual elements of the initial large array and write a function that assigns the colors/full/empty based on that it would be much simpler. Tnx also for your searches. You've made the world more forgiving.

I’m glad you like it. The focus is on avoiding the dataset.source parameter. I separately generated the data arrays for the two charts (named candlestickData and volumeData) and created the X-axis values separately (named dateData). I then injected these into the appropriate places: series.data and xAxis.data. This allowed us to take advantage of the extra properties of series.data. The rawData is simply the initial setup for these three arrays. If you assemble rawData according to your own logic, the other three arrays will be correctly generated by my code.

I like it, but but I was a little disappointed. On the site there are graphs of buses, cows and many other things that are of no use to anyone and to make a graph that the whole world uses you have to use the trick of separating volumes and candles. It's Apache . What the heck. It has the best web servers in the world and a stupid graph has to be so much customized to work graphically.

Doing all this splitting and inject the graphic element makes it harder to add and remove points each time. It also makes it harder to do a "live" switch from line to candle. That's why I would leave the data intact, do a (-1,1) push on the single point, and work that with a custom function for the candles if possible.

I think that what i want to do it's itemStyle: generateItemStyle(elemet) in option where element it's a simple array (not a collection) like this ["2004-02-04", 10503.11, 10470.74, 10394.81, 10567.85, 227760000, -1] and -1 it's added before on data from a data.map or a data.foreach as you want. So I have not to split data. This is a much much better solution and leaves the possibility to make an instant change from line to candle with a simple setOption( ... {type: 'line'}, itemStyle: { color: '#008ffb', }, ...). It's possibile like this?

@user27160653 Good idea, I added a new code snippet to my answer, where I quickly made a demo for you. Extra: I looked into it, and in the case of custom coloring, there is no color0 and borderColor0; you have to decide whether it's decreasing or not. --> I wrote an example for this as well, purple is for increasing, blue is for decreasing, but you'll definitely see that.

Maybe I didn't explain myself well. I don't want to split the data because it's much easier to enter them as points. And what is this blue and purple? My eyes are going stupid. In financial charts they use red and green. I'll edit the question with some code to make it clearer.

Hi! I'm trying to help. I'm sorry that I'm driving you crazy. In ECharts, if you have an array, you need to split it into at least two parts to add uniqueness to each value. In the second code snippet I left for you, you can pass an array (as rawData) to the whole thing, and the code will split it for you, dynamically assigning a unique style to the appropriate values. Your task here is simply to customize the conditions for dynamic style assignment.

yes I'm going a little mad, but not so much. Ok, your solution it's good and it adapts to the demand, but it's too complex. Every time a point becomes a collection and I have no idea I'm going crazy really when I have to add points or delete them (by coding the searching of them one by one, checking the number on the series, checking other things etc). So please read the edit id the answer and say me if you can adapt the code work like this. I can't find anything in the documentation. Tnx so much anyway. You were helpful (after understanding, blue and violet man )

Maybe, you would just need a function that adds it to everything else as well (since the new live data will always be the last one), and this way you wouldn't need to regenerate the candlestickData and dateData from the very large rawData. Of course, this only works if you don't want to modify the coloring of the already existing elements.

this is the simplest thing. I don't want live data only on the last element, but I would like to be able to modify the graph's data on the first ones (or even in the middle) through an external function by adding or removing points (candlesticks). Also i want to make a dynamic change by candlestick, to candlestick hollow/solid, line graph. So if it is possible to do what I ask (without splitting the array that it works with everything i say), fine, otherwise the answer is your great helper.

Yes, I was afraid you would want to manipulate the existing data as well. Well, I don't think I can help with that. If anything comes up, I'll let you know.

Eminem says you don't have be afraid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5-yKhDd64s you have been a great help. It's what i want to do with datas. Waiting for some plugins or some new eCharts version

P.S. As you wrote you are not the only one who will read this post because I think it's interesting for those in the financial sector, so maybe someone will see it with a more advanced answer. Although I think it may take some time. Bye and thanks

Also after the Update 2 i'm not satisfied. (Apart from the fact that I didn't understand the proxy thing) you are splitting the data, the "live" transition from line to candlestick with a simple setOption is very complicated, you are passing each time a whole array of points when you update the chart (instead of passing just one in a single position), in addition to performing millions of operations as you wrote. Anyway thanks a lot really again

Solution
Candlestick solid and hollow display
You can handle this by configuring the series-candlestick.itemStyle for the candlestick series.
itemStyle: {
  color: 'transparent',     // Hollow candle (upward movement)
  color0: '#ec0000',        // Solid candle (downward movement)
  borderColor: '#00da3c',   // Border for hollow candles (upward movement)
  borderColor0: '#ec0000',  // Border for solid candles (downward movement)
},

Uniform volume color
You can control this in the series-bar.itemStyle.
{
  name: 'Volume',
  type: 'bar',
  xAxisIndex: 1,
  yAxisIndex: 1,
  itemStyle: {
    color: 'azure',  // Uniform volume color
  },
}

Example


var chartDom = document.getElementById('main')
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom)
var option

const upColor = '#00da3c'
const downColor = '#ec0000'

var rawData = [["2004-01-02",10452.74,10409.85,10367.41,10554.96,168890000],["2004-01-05",10411.85,10544.07,10411.85,10575.92,221290000],["2004-01-06",10543.85,10538.66,10454.37,10584.07,191460000],["2004-01-07",10535.46,10529.03,10432,10587.55,225490000],["2004-01-08",10530.07,10592.44,10480.59,10651.99,237770000],["2004-01-09",10589.25,10458.89,10420.52,10603.48,223250000],["2004-01-12",10461.55,10485.18,10389.85,10543.03,197960000],["2004-01-13",10485.18,10427.18,10341.19,10539.25,197310000],["2004-01-14",10428.67,10538.37,10426.89,10573.85,186280000],["2004-01-15",10534.52,10553.85,10454.52,10639.03,260090000],["2004-01-16",10556.37,10600.51,10503.7,10666.88,254170000],["2004-01-20",10601.4,10528.66,10447.92,10676.96,224300000],["2004-01-21",10522.77,10623.62,10453.11,10665.7,214920000],["2004-01-22",10624.22,10623.18,10545.03,10717.4,219720000],["2004-01-23",10625.25,10568.29,10490.14,10691.77,234260000],["2004-01-26",10568,10702.51,10510.44,10725.18,186170000],["2004-01-27",10701.1,10609.92,10579.33,10748.81,206560000],["2004-01-28",10610.07,10468.37,10412.44,10703.25,247660000],["2004-01-29",10467.41,10510.29,10369.92,10611.56,273970000],["2004-01-30",10510.22,10488.07,10385.56,10551.03,208990000],["2004-02-02",10487.78,10499.18,10395.55,10614.44,224800000],["2004-02-03",10499.48,10505.18,10414.15,10571.48,183810000],["2004-02-04",10503.11,10470.74,10394.81,10567.85,227760000],["2004-02-05",10469.33,10495.55,10399.92,10566.37,187810000]]

myChart.setOption(
  (option = {
    dataset: {
      source: rawData,
    },
    animation: false,
    legend: {
      bottom: 10,
      left: 'center',
      data: ['Dow-Jones index'],
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'axis',
      axisPointer: {
        type: 'cross',
      },
    },
    axisPointer: {
      link: [
        {
          xAxisIndex: 'all',
        },
      ],
    },
    toolbox: {
      feature: {
        dataZoom: {
          yAxisIndex: false,
        },
      },
    },
    grid: [
      {
        left: '10%',
        right: '8%',
        height: '50%',
      },
      {
        left: '10%',
        right: '8%',
        top: '63%',
        height: '16%',
      },
    ],
    xAxis: [
      {
        type: 'category',
        boundaryGap: false,
        axisLine: { onZero: false },
        splitLine: { show: false },
        min: 'dataMin',
        max: 'dataMax',
      },
      {
        type: 'category',
        gridIndex: 1,
        boundaryGap: false,
        axisLine: { onZero: false },
        axisTick: { show: false },
        splitLine: { show: false },
        axisLabel: { show: false },
        min: 'dataMin',
        max: 'dataMax',
      },
    ],
    yAxis: [
      {
        scale: true,
        splitArea: {
          show: true,
        },
      },
      {
        scale: true,
        gridIndex: 1,
        splitNumber: 2,
        axisLabel: { show: false },
        axisLine: { show: false },
        axisTick: { show: false },
        splitLine: { show: false },
      },
    ],
    dataZoom: [
      {
        type: 'inside',
        xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
        start: 0,
        end: 100,
      },
      {
        show: true,
        xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
        type: 'slider',
        top: '85%',
        start: 0,
        end: 100,
      },
    ],
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Dow-Jones index',
        type: 'candlestick',
        // Changed
        itemStyle: {
          color: 'transparent',    // Hollow candles (upward movement)
          color0: downColor,       // Solid candles (downward movement)
          borderColor: upColor,    // Border for hollow candles (upward movement)
          borderColor0: downColor, // Border for solid candles (downward movement)
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Volume',
        type: 'bar',
        xAxisIndex: 1,
        yAxisIndex: 1,
        // Added
        itemStyle: {
          color: 'azure',          // Uniform volume color
        },
      },
    ],
  })
)
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>



More information

series-candlestick.itemStyle - ECharts Docs

color property - ECharts Docs
color0 property - ECharts Docs
borderColor property - ECharts Docs
borderColor0 property - ECharts Docs


series-bar.itemStyle - ECharts Docs

color property - ECharts Docs




Something wrong. Candles are always red full or green empty. I added some move values to chek it here https://jsfiddle.net/o0nu98f5/1/
Also the volumns and caldles are on 2 different grids. Anyway thanks.

You've added more values, I understand, but this has made the space smaller, and it's only the lack of pixels that's confusing you. The result is the same as in my example; zoom in and you'll see. If I were to display 3 billion values, you simply wouldn't be able to analyze the data because every line would be so thin, it can be intensified.

In my solution, I gave the 'up' values a transparent background and a green outline, so according to the Wikipedia image, it follows the 'solid-hollow' style for upwards values. For the 'down' values, I applied a red background and a red outline, making it appear as a 'filled' rectangle, consistent with the mentioned example. Please clarify your question if this answer doesn't meet your expectations. However, providing an unreasonably large amount of X-axis data is not correct. Keep a realistic perspective; for instance, only display as many items on the X-axis as can be comfortably rendered.

Maybe I didn't explain myself well. I added more values ​​not to make you see a million values, but to have more feedback on the candles. It's not the pixels that confuse me. If you zoom in you will notice that the candles are only of two types: empty green and full red (that's why more values). I don't think it's a background issue. Look at the result: https://ibb.co/0Cmj7Mm I absolutely don't see a single full green candle. Also in your solution both volume and candles are on the same grid. The question is very clear and the values ​​on the x-axis have increased but are easily renderable.

The Wikipedia image it's correct. It's the resulting graph that gives a strange visual output (besides wanting both values ​​on the same grid)

@user27160653 the red candels should be full and the green one empty, that's my understanding of the wiki article too. Or you can make all in the same color (as on wikipedia). But what is the meaning of a green full one, or a red empty one?

Hi kikon! Current close price referred to current open price: Solid/Hollow (full or only bordered). Previous close price - actual close price Red/Green. It's in Wikipedia reported. It's undestendable. There are an X values and 4 values for the Y (open, close, low, high). "the red candels should be full and the green one empty" it's not true everytime. It could be the opposite

Source tradingview.com Title Tesla https://ibb.co/1fhsPrf

Some series color or hollow/solid are important signal for financials. If you want to know something about (the list is actually much longer): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_pattern#Simple_patterns

Ah, this is a much better illustrative example! I understand your concerns!

@rozsazoltan Sometimes a picture says more than a written book.

At first glance, I would say that ECharts can only color them uniformly. I will write a new response if I happen to find a solution.

Thanks. It seems to me too this thing of the uniform color in ECHARTS. I wait for a solution from someone writing. In any case you could map the initial array adding a value at the end (-1 and 1 calculated by an external function). I do not know how to assign the internal and border colors to the single candle.

I also add that advanced financial charts allow you to draw sloped lines/trend lines/channel lines etc directly on the chart. Can you imagine having to print a chart every time and draw on it when in 2024 there are technological means? However I believe this can be done with some magic trick.

@user27160653 to make things more clear for those (like me) that have no idea about the meaning of these terms: the echarts candlestick has "open", "close", "high" and "low". Since high is always on top and low always down, there are only two possibilities, depending on the relative position of "open" and "close" (bullish and bearish). Now, you talk about "previous open" and "current open" , "previous close" and "current close". Does "previous" mean that we have to actually look to the previous candle when we make the color of the current one? What about the first candle that has no previous?

@kinon you can understand how not to understand financial things but comparing two values ​​twice is not difficult. There are four conditions. They are in the question. It is so simple that I do not understand how it can seem difficult. This result can generate 4 type of candles.

"Now, you talk about "previous open" and "current open" , "previous close" and "current close". Does "previous" mean that we have to actually look at the previous candle when we make the color of the current one? What about the first candle that has no previous?". EXACTLY. Make the first candle as you wish. It is advisable to make it full if it has no precedent. But there is always a precedent, unless you look at the day the title was created. P.S. bullish and bearish are concepts that go a little little beyond this discussion (a single candle means nothing)
