How to get the first and the last point values in ECHARTS of the visible zone on the screen when it's initialized and on resize
I'm trying to get back the first and the last value in ECHARTS on a graph like this
where there's also a zoomable zone
I've tryied
<script>
var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);

function test(){
    console.log(myChart.getOption());
}
test();
</script>


that gives back the series object after initialization.
So you can get back the first and last coords like this
    first_serie_coords = myChart.getOption().series[0].coords;  //depends on how you provided the data
    first_element = first_serie_coords[0]
    last_element = first_serie_coords[first_serie_coords.length - 1]
    console.log(first_element, last_element)

But how to get the start and the end point when the graph's zooming zone it's initialized and then resized?
Here's a snippet to work on easy (open it in full screen)


  rawData = [
      ["2004-01-02",10452.74,10409.85,10367.41,10554.96,168890000],
      ["2004-01-05",10411.85,10544.07,10411.85,10575.92,221290000],
      ["2004-01-06",10543.85,10538.66,10454.37,10584.07,191460000],
      ["2004-01-07",10535.46,10529.03,10432,10587.55,225490000],
      ["2004-01-08",10530.07,10592.44,10480.59,10651.99,237770000],
      ["2004-01-09",10589.25,10458.89,10420.52,10603.48,223250000],
      ["2004-01-12",10461.55,10485.18,10389.85,10543.03,197960000],
      ["2004-01-13",10485.18,10427.18,10341.19,10539.25,197310000],
      ["2004-01-14",10428.67,10538.37,10426.89,10573.85,186280000],
      ["2004-01-15",10534.52,10553.85,10454.52,10639.03,260090000],
      ["2004-01-16",10556.37,10600.51,10503.7,10666.88,254170000],
      ["2004-01-20",10601.4,10528.66,10447.92,10676.96,224300000],
      ["2004-01-21",10522.77,10623.62,10453.11,10665.7,214920000],
      ["2004-01-22",10624.22,10623.18,10545.03,10717.4,219720000],
      ["2004-01-23",10625.25,10568.29,10490.14,10691.77,234260000],
      ["2004-01-26",10568,10702.51,10510.44,10725.18,186170000],
      ["2004-01-27",10701.1,10609.92,10579.33,10748.81,206560000],
      ["2004-01-28",10610.07,10468.37,10412.44,10703.25,247660000],
      ["2004-01-29",10467.41,10510.29,10369.92,10611.56,273970000],
      ["2004-01-30",10510.22,10488.07,10385.56,10551.03,208990000],
      ["2004-02-02",10487.78,10499.18,10395.55,10614.44,224800000],
      ["2004-02-03",10499.48,10505.18,10414.15,10571.48,183810000],
      ["2004-02-04",10503.11,10470.74,10394.81,10567.85,227760000],
      ["2004-02-05",10469.33,10495.55,10399.92,10566.37,187810000],
      ["2004-02-06",10494.89,10593.03,10433.7,10634.81,182880000],
      ["2004-02-09",10592,10579.03,10433.7,10634.81,160720000],   
  ]
  
var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

const upColor = '#00da3c';
const downColor = '#ec0000';
function splitData(rawData) {
  let categoryData = [];
  let values = [];
  let volumes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
    categoryData.push(rawData[i].splice(0, 1)[0]);
    values.push(rawData[i]);
    volumes.push([i, rawData[i][4], rawData[i][0] > rawData[i][1] ? 1 : -1]);
  }
  return {
    categoryData: categoryData,
    values: values,
    volumes: volumes
  };
}
function calculateMA(dayCount, data) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = data.values.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i < dayCount) {
      result.push('-');
      continue;
    }
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < dayCount; j++) {
      sum += data.values[i - j][1];
    }
    result.push(+(sum / dayCount).toFixed(3));
  }
  return result;
}
//$.get('https://echarts.apache.org/examples/data/asset/data/stock-DJI.json', function (rawData) {
    
    
    

    
  var data = splitData(rawData);
  //console.log(data);
  myChart.setOption(
    (option = {
      animation: false,
      legend: {
        bottom: 10,
        left: 'center',
        data: ['Dow-Jones index', 'MA5', 'MA10', 'MA20', 'MA30']
      },
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
          type: 'cross'
        },
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        padding: 10,
        textStyle: {
          color: '#000'
        },
        position: function (pos, params, el, elRect, size) {
          const obj = {
            top: 10
          };
          obj[['left', 'right'][+(pos[0] < size.viewSize[0] / 2)]] = 30;
          return obj;
        }
        // extraCssText: 'width: 170px'
      },
      axisPointer: {
        link: [
          {
            xAxisIndex: 'all'
          }
        ],
        label: {
          backgroundColor: '#777'
        }
      },
      toolbox: {
        feature: {
          dataZoom: {
            yAxisIndex: false
          },
          brush: {
            type: ['lineX', 'clear']
          }
        }
      },
      visualMap: {
        show: false,
        seriesIndex: 5,
        dimension: 2,
        pieces: [
          {
            value: 1,
            color: downColor
          },
          {
            value: -1,
            color: upColor
          }
        ]
      },
      grid: [
        {
          left: '10%',
          right: '8%',
          height: '50%'
        },
        {
          left: '10%',
          right: '8%',
          top: '63%',
          height: '16%'
        }
      ],
      xAxis: [
        {
          type: 'category',
          data: data.categoryData,
          boundaryGap: false,
          axisLine: { onZero: false },
          splitLine: { show: false },
          min: 'dataMin',
          max: 'dataMax',
          axisPointer: {
            z: 100
          }
        },
        {
          type: 'category',
          gridIndex: 1,
          data: data.categoryData,
          boundaryGap: false,
          axisLine: { onZero: false },
          axisTick: { show: false },
          splitLine: { show: false },
          axisLabel: { show: false },
          min: 'dataMin',
          max: 'dataMax'
        }
      ],
      yAxis: [
        {
          scale: true,
          splitArea: {
            show: true
          }
        },
        {
          scale: true,
          gridIndex: 1,
          splitNumber: 2,
          axisLabel: { show: false },
          axisLine: { show: false },
          axisTick: { show: false },
          splitLine: { show: false }
        }
      ],
      dataZoom: [
        {
          type: 'inside',
          xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
          start: 50,
          end: 100
        },
        {
          show: true,
          xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
          type: 'slider',
          top: '85%',
          start: 50,
          end: 100
        }
      ],
      series: [
        {
          name: 'Dow-Jones index',
          type: 'candlestick',
          data: data.values,
          itemStyle: {
            color: upColor,
            color0: downColor,
            borderColor: undefined,
            borderColor0: undefined
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'MA5',
          type: 'line',
          data: calculateMA(5, data),
          smooth: true,
          lineStyle: {
            opacity: 0.5
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'MA10',
          type: 'line',
          data: calculateMA(10, data),
          smooth: true,
          lineStyle: {
            opacity: 0.5
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'MA20',
          type: 'line',
          data: calculateMA(20, data),
          smooth: true,
          lineStyle: {
            opacity: 0.5
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'MA30',
          type: 'line',
          data: calculateMA(30, data),
          smooth: true,
          lineStyle: {
            opacity: 0.5
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'Volume',
          type: 'bar',
          xAxisIndex: 1,
          yAxisIndex: 1,
          data: data.volumes
        }
      ]
    }),
    true
  );
  //});

option && myChart.setOption(option);




//console.log(myChart);
//console.log(myChart.getOption());

first_serie_coords = myChart.getOption().series[0].data;
first_element = first_serie_coords[0];
last_element = first_serie_coords[first_serie_coords.length - 1];

console.log(first_element, last_element);
<div id="main" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>




A dataZoom component configured through the
option object, (like those you implemented in your code), when passed through the
setOption method and
retrieved through getOption
gets completed with default and computed values.
The computed values you may use to determine the first and last visible data items under zoom
are .startValue,
and .endValue,
which are available for both the type: 'inside' and type: 'slider' dataZoom objects;
for a category x axis like it is your case, their computed values are the indices of the first and
last visible axis categories, which are also the indices of the first and last visible data items
(assuming there are no null data entries).
See also rangeMode
for solutions in the case the x axis is not of type category but of type value.
So, your code can be adapted to use these properties:
....................
myChart.setOption(option);
const optionFull = myChart.getOption();
const first_serie_coords = optionFull.series[0].data;
const dataZoom = optionFull.dataZoom[0];

const startValue = dataZoom && dataZoom.startValue || 0,
    endValue = dataZoom && dataZoom.endValue || first_serie_coords.length - 1;
const first_element = first_serie_coords[startValue];
const last_element = first_serie_coords[endValue];
console.log(first_element, last_element);

And the snippet adapted, with some more details:


rawData = [
      ["2004-01-02",10452.74,10409.85,10367.41,10554.96,168890000],
      ["2004-01-05",10411.85,10544.07,10411.85,10575.92,221290000],
      ["2004-01-06",10543.85,10538.66,10454.37,10584.07,191460000],
      ["2004-01-07",10535.46,10529.03,10432,10587.55,225490000],
      ["2004-01-08",10530.07,10592.44,10480.59,10651.99,237770000],
      ["2004-01-09",10589.25,10458.89,10420.52,10603.48,223250000],
      ["2004-01-12",10461.55,10485.18,10389.85,10543.03,197960000],
      ["2004-01-13",10485.18,10427.18,10341.19,10539.25,197310000],
      ["2004-01-14",10428.67,10538.37,10426.89,10573.85,186280000],
      ["2004-01-15",10534.52,10553.85,10454.52,10639.03,260090000],
      ["2004-01-16",10556.37,10600.51,10503.7,10666.88,254170000],
      ["2004-01-20",10601.4,10528.66,10447.92,10676.96,224300000],
      ["2004-01-21",10522.77,10623.62,10453.11,10665.7,214920000],
      ["2004-01-22",10624.22,10623.18,10545.03,10717.4,219720000],
      ["2004-01-23",10625.25,10568.29,10490.14,10691.77,234260000],
      ["2004-01-26",10568,10702.51,10510.44,10725.18,186170000],
      ["2004-01-27",10701.1,10609.92,10579.33,10748.81,206560000],
      ["2004-01-28",10610.07,10468.37,10412.44,10703.25,247660000],
      ["2004-01-29",10467.41,10510.29,10369.92,10611.56,273970000],
      ["2004-01-30",10510.22,10488.07,10385.56,10551.03,208990000],
      ["2004-02-02",10487.78,10499.18,10395.55,10614.44,224800000],
      ["2004-02-03",10499.48,10505.18,10414.15,10571.48,183810000],
      ["2004-02-04",10503.11,10470.74,10394.81,10567.85,227760000],
      ["2004-02-05",10469.33,10495.55,10399.92,10566.37,187810000],
      ["2004-02-06",10494.89,10593.03,10433.7,10634.81,182880000],
      ["2004-02-09",10592,10579.03,10433.7,10634.81,160720000],   
  ]
  
var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

const upColor = '#00da3c';
const downColor = '#ec0000';
function splitData(rawData) {
  let categoryData = [];
  let values = [];
  let volumes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
    categoryData.push(rawData[i].splice(0, 1)[0]);
    values.push(rawData[i]);
    volumes.push([i, rawData[i][4], rawData[i][0] > rawData[i][1] ? 1 : -1]);
  }
  return {
    categoryData: categoryData,
    values: values,
    volumes: volumes
  };
}
function calculateMA(dayCount, data) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = data.values.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i < dayCount) {
      result.push('-');
      continue;
    }
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < dayCount; j++) {
      sum += data.values[i - j][1];
    }
    result.push(+(sum / dayCount).toFixed(3));
  }
  return result;
}
//$.get('https://echarts.apache.org/examples/data/asset/data/stock-DJI.json', function (rawData) {
    
    
    

    
  var data = splitData(rawData);
  //console.log(data);
  myChart.setOption(
    (option = {
      animation: false,
      legend: {
        bottom: 10,
        left: 'center',
        data: ['Dow-Jones index', 'MA5', 'MA10', 'MA20', 'MA30']
      },
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
          type: 'cross'
        },
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        padding: 10,
        textStyle: {
          color: '#000'
        },
        position: function (pos, params, el, elRect, size) {
          const obj = {
            top: 10
          };
          obj[['left', 'right'][+(pos[0] < size.viewSize[0] / 2)]] = 30;
          return obj;
        }
        // extraCssText: 'width: 170px'
      },
      axisPointer: {
        link: [
          {
            xAxisIndex: 'all'
          }
        ],
        label: {
          backgroundColor: '#777'
        }
      },
      toolbox: {
        feature: {
          dataZoom: {
            yAxisIndex: false
          },
          brush: {
            type: ['lineX', 'clear']
          }
        }
      },
      visualMap: {
        show: false,
        seriesIndex: 5,
        dimension: 2,
        pieces: [
          {
            value: 1,
            color: downColor
          },
          {
            value: -1,
            color: upColor
          }
        ]
      },
      grid: [
        {
          left: '10%',
          right: '8%',
          height: '50%'
        },
        {
          left: '10%',
          right: '8%',
          top: '63%',
          height: '16%'
        }
      ],
      xAxis: [
        {
          type: 'category',
          data: data.categoryData,
          boundaryGap: false,
          axisLine: { onZero: false },
          splitLine: { show: false },
          min: 'dataMin',
          max: 'dataMax',
          axisPointer: {
            z: 100
          }
        },
        {
          type: 'category',
          gridIndex: 1,
          data: data.categoryData,
          boundaryGap: false,
          axisLine: { onZero: false },
          axisTick: { show: false },
          splitLine: { show: false },
          axisLabel: { show: false },
          min: 'dataMin',
          max: 'dataMax'
        }
      ],
      yAxis: [
        {
          scale: true,
          splitArea: {
            show: true
          }
        },
        {
          scale: true,
          gridIndex: 1,
          splitNumber: 2,
          axisLabel: { show: false },
          axisLine: { show: false },
          axisTick: { show: false },
          splitLine: { show: false }
        }
      ],
      dataZoom: [
        {
          type: 'inside',
          xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
          start: 50,
          end: 100
        },
        {
          show: true,
          xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
          type: 'slider',
          top: '85%',
          start: 50,
          end: 100
        }
      ],
      series: [
        {
          name: 'Dow-Jones index',
          type: 'candlestick',
          data: data.values,
          itemStyle: {
            color: upColor,
            color0: downColor,
            borderColor: undefined,
            borderColor0: undefined
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'MA5',
          type: 'line',
          data: calculateMA(5, data),
          smooth: true,
          lineStyle: {
            opacity: 0.5
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'MA10',
          type: 'line',
          data: calculateMA(10, data),
          smooth: true,
          lineStyle: {
            opacity: 0.5
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'MA20',
          type: 'line',
          data: calculateMA(20, data),
          smooth: true,
          lineStyle: {
            opacity: 0.5
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'MA30',
          type: 'line',
          data: calculateMA(30, data),
          smooth: true,
          lineStyle: {
            opacity: 0.5
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'Volume',
          type: 'bar',
          xAxisIndex: 1,
          yAxisIndex: 1,
          data: data.volumes
        }
      ]
    }),
    true
  );
  //});

myChart.setOption(option);

function getExtremeVisiblePoints(){
  const optionFull = myChart.getOption();
  const first_serie_coords = optionFull.series[0].data;
  const dataZoom = optionFull.dataZoom[0];

  const startValue = dataZoom && dataZoom.startValue || 0,
    endValue = dataZoom && dataZoom.endValue || first_serie_coords.length - 1;
  const first_element = first_serie_coords[startValue];
  const last_element = first_serie_coords[endValue];
  
  document.querySelector('#point1').innerText = first_element;
  document.querySelector('#point2').innerText = last_element;
  //console.log({startValue, endValue})
  //console.log({first_element, last_element});
}
myChart.on('datazoom', ()=>{
    document.querySelector('#point1').innerText = '';
    document.querySelector('#point2').innerText = '';
});
<button onclick="getExtremeVisiblePoints()">Get Extreme Visible Points</button><br>
<code id="point1" style="font-size: small"></code><br>
<code id="point2" style="font-size: small"></code>
<div id="main" style="width: 500px;height: 500px"></div>


<div id="main" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>




@ kinon exactly what i need for the code. Perfect solution. Good answer to the question also complete. I have to try if it works also when initialized. Answer solved and accepted. Useful correct answer. You added also the return 0 for the first point and the last point if null. Special thanks.

@user27160653, in regards to your question about extending this to multiple charts: Yes, I think it's possible, but I'm not sure what's the difficulty, I'd just apply the same function - with myChart as a parameter - for each chart. Can you please give me an example of multiple charts so can better understand what you have in minds. Here's the previous code in a jsfiddle if it helps.

Nono for now go easy. I was wrong. I should learn to read better before commenting. After waching your code it's perfect. I thought that the data variables were stored in the code tag instead you get them directly from the chart. You use myChart.on('datazoom' exclusively to reset the visual part of the page. Good Js. Thank also for the fiddle. Since you are so helpful, if you want to take a look at this too (the question is a little more complex) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78947862/how-to-get-in-a-candlestick-echarts-graph-candles-solid-hollow-and-how-to-get-th

Just an other thing about this question that i don't understand. If the graph it's filled with dataset.source instead of series.data i don't have nothing about coord in chart.getOption().series[0].coords. And I don't see a replacement variable to take the coord values. How do I get them?

OK, stupid question. myChart.getOption().dataset[0].source. Thanks @ kinon
